# regex to match strings between two different separators like "<" and ">"

Tags: python, regex, separator

I want to split my text into contexts and captures where I have rules like:

```
<abc> e f <ghi>
<abc> e f
e f <ghi>
```

Here I want to create rules that only affect strings inside of the markers `<>`
and example would be the output:

```
<aabbcc> e f <gghhii>
<axyzbxyzcxyz> e f 
e f <g_h_i_>
```

using `line.split('')[i]` doesn't cut it because I have two different separators

Comment: Don't use `split`. Use `re.search` using `r'<([^>]*)>'` regex and get captured group #1

Comment: maybe this expression in re.findall?

Comment: Yes that regex will work fine in `re.findall`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) to replace the parts within `<...>`, using a replacement callback function:

```
def replace_function(match):
    return '<' + ''.join(c + c for c in match.group(1)) + '>'

text = re.sub(r"<(.*?)>", replace_function, text)
```

This will duplicate the chars in each of the tags, but you can extend the function any way you want to perform more complex substitutions.